# Problem with bidirectional onetomany relationship in jpa (missing the id of one of the entities when created)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

So, I have a **OneToMany** relationship between two classes called **Customer** and **Address**.

In the **Customer** class I have:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="customer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Address> addresses;
```

And in **Address** I have:

```
@ManyToOne(optional=false)
private Customer customer;
```

Now, when I try to create a new customer with its address everything works just fine, but in the Addresses table on my database, the column customer_id is null and I don't know why.
I thought **CascadeType.ALL** would've done all of this linking job. I've also tried adding a JoinColumn on the relationship on the Address side, but that didn't work either.
What should I do? I hope I've been clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you are saving the both side of the reference since it is a bi-directional relationship.

In `Customer` class create a method like this:

```
public void addAddresses(Address address) {
    addresses.add(address);
    address.setCustomer(this);
}
```

Then, create `Customer` and add `addresses`:

```
Customer c = new Customer();
c.addAddresses(new Address());
customerRepository.save(customer);
```